# PHP ImageMagick get image from http

Tags: php, http, imagemagick

I am trying to use ImageMagick for some photo manipulation (crop for the moment). I succeed previously the desired outcome by using GD library for PHP (on my localhost) but now the hosting doesn't support it and they suggest me to use ImageMagick instead. The issue is that I can crop an image that it is stored locally :

```
<?php
$four = '4fingers1.jpg';
exec("convert $four -crop 100x100+100+100 test.jpg");
?>
<img src="test.jpg">
```

with no problem but when it comes from http sources (the actual purpose of my script) I receive no image. The code is the following (I post with a form the actual src of the image):

```
$src = $_POST['src'];
exec("convert $src -resize 720x720 resized.jpg"); // this is specified in the documentation
exec("convert resized.jpg -crop 100x100+100+100 final.jpg");
?>
<img src="final.jpg"> <!-- no image -->
<img src="resized.jpg"> <!-- no image -->
<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>"> <!-- alright -->
```

The documentation specify the following:

> IM can also download an image that is published on the 'world wide
>   web' by specifying that images URL. This basically provides a 'http:'
>   image coder, which is why it works.

Link: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#read

I've tried a lots of code snippets founded online and can't figure it out why is not working? I can use maybe something else to reach my purpose?

Comment: be very careful with your `$_POST['src']` & `exec`.

Comment: I've searched for other solutions but nothing seems to suits my need that I am aware of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm with the answer of Jon and the comment of Prisoner. You'll have to escape the $src POST var to prevent from shell command injection using [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php):

```
$src = escapeshellarg($_POST);
```

Further you should use the second param (output of command) and the third param (return value of command) and respect it.

Call [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) like this:

```
exec("convert $src -resize 720x720 resized.jpg 2>&1", $output, $returnval);

if($returnval !== 0) {
    die('imagemagick error: ' . join("<br/>", $output));
}
```

Now you are able to react on errors and you can see what's going wrong. Note that I've redirected stderr of imagemagick to stdout using shell redirection ( `2>&1` )

Comment: Thank you in the first place for the prompt reply. I've followed your suggestion regarding `escapeshellarg` and unfortunately I receive the following error: `imagemagick error: Array`. What this means? I have to iterate it to find the error value/code or something similar?

Comment: Sorry, my fault! ;) I missed that $output will be an array of lines. Check my update

Comment: No problem, your help is great. The good side is that the Array part is gone but the bad side is that now I only receive `imagemagick error:`... I could try Jon's suggestion of handling temp files, maybe this could help?

Comment: Yes you can try (and should), but imagemagick supports http downloads (As you've mentioned). Is it http or https?

Comment: You should redirect stderr to stdout. Like this `2>&1` .. Check my update

Comment: Is https and I will try your update now, hope it clarify my problem.

Comment: Update: I receive the following errors: `imagemagick error: sh: @WWWDecodeDelegateDefault@: command not found
convert: Delegate failed '"@WWWDecodeDelegateDefault@" -q -O "%o" "https:%i"'.`

Comment: Ok, now we know more :).. Can you post the output to pastebin and share the link? (it looks like that the output you've posted in commend is cutted)

Comment: Can you add the output of `var_dump($_POST['src']);` to your question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CgFFPuze <- The pastebin and `var_dump($_POST['src']);` = `string(102) "https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/s720x720/166788_430551377028616_545387584_n.jpg" `

Comment: When I try to open `https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/s720x720/166788_43055137%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B7028616_545387584_n.jpg` in browser I get 'invalid request'. Maybe this is the problem? I tried with several other https images and it works

Comment: It is because of the copy and paste to stackoverflow. The image is shown in the response if I put it in the img tag. I research something and I am able now to get the cropped picture. I will post an answer down, feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, as Prisoner [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765100/php-imagemagick-get-image-from-http#comment22407539_15765100) this code is vulnerable to shell argument injection. Basically anyone can manipulate the post parameters and cause you to execute any command line they want; **this is potentially disastrous and should be addressed immediately!**

One way to fix the security issue is use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php); this should also fix your "original" problem since there is no apparent reason for the command to fail. If the URL is valid and the argument is properly escaped it should just work.

Alternatively, you can solve both the security headache and your original problem by downloading the image yourself and saving it to a temporary file before calling IM:

```
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir());
file_put_contents($temp, file_get_contents($url));

exec("convert ".escapeshellarg($temp)." -crop 100x100+100+100 test.jpg");
```

Comment: Nice example regarding saving to a temporary file. It is something that I really need. Thank you. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that IM have a problem with the https protocol in my case. I've tested with a http image and everything was working fine so I made the following:

```
<?php
$src = $_POST['src'];
$src = preg_replace('/^https\:\/\//', 'http://', $src);
$src = escapeshellarg($src);
exec('convert ' . $src . ' resized.jpg 2>&1', $output, $returnval);
if($returnval !== 0) {
    die('imagemagick error: ' . join("<br/>", $output));
}
?>
<img src="resized.jpg">
```

I have the image now displayed and I can start crop it and so on.

Comment: Can it be, that the site is using an untrusted certificate which causes the problem?

Comment: I am not aware of this but it could be the issue in my case, I haven't tried actually with other https images.